# How can I obtain 80 percent code coverage in C

Tags: c, testing

For this I need to write code in my two functions inputchar() and inputstring(). When I do this I need to get the code coverage when ran against the testme() function to at least 80 percent. While running GCOV I am only getting 17 percent coverage, and have bounced around from 17-23 percent. Does anyone have any suggestions/help? I am new to C and creating random testers like this.

The only code that needs to be modified is inputchar file and the inputstring file

```
char inputChar()
{
  char random = (rand() % 94) + 32;
      return random;
}

char *inputString()
{

static char s[6];
s[0] = 'r';
s[1] = 'e';
s[2] = 's';
s[3] = 'e';
s[4] = 't';
s[5] = '\0';

int i;

for(i = 0; i<6;i++) {

  s[i]++;
  i++;
}

return s;
}

void testme()
{
  int tcCount = 0;
  char *s;
  char c;
  int state = 0;
  while (1)
  {
    tcCount++;
    c = inputChar();
    s = inputString();
    printf("Iteration %d: c = %c, s = %s, state = %d\n", tcCount, c, s, state);

    if (c == '[' && state == 0) state = 1;
    if (c == '(' && state == 1) state = 2;
    if (c == '{' && state == 2) state = 3;
    if (c == ' '&& state == 3) state = 4;
    if (c == 'a' && state == 4) state = 5;
    if (c == 'x' && state == 5) state = 6;
    if (c == '}' && state == 6) state = 7;
    if (c == ')' && state == 7) state = 8;
    if (c == ']' && state == 8) state = 9;
    if (s[0] == 'r' && s[1] == 'e'
       && s[2] == 's' && s[3] == 'e'
       && s[4] == 't' && s[5] == '\0'
       && state == 9)
    {
      printf("error ");
      exit(200);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't test with randoms. Read the code to be tested an define input which is speicifically targeted to get you through each path of the to-be-tested function. You are aware that passing each path is the goal of this, aren't you?

Comment: Debug while testing and observe which path is passed and which not, then extend the tests to also pass the missing paths.

Comment: To be more specific: Ask yourself "How do I get the statement `state=9` executed?" That is your goal. My first comment is the key to achieve that. Also to NOT execute the `exit(200)` statement before that goal is achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Don't test with randoms; not when code coverage is the goal.
Read the code to be tested and define input which is specifically targeted to get you through each path of the to-be-tested function. You are aware that passing each path is the goal of this, aren't you?
To make this easier, debug while testing and observe which path is passed and which not, then extend the tests to also pass the missing paths. For that you need to write the testing program for yourself. Looks like the test can only be just calling the `testme` function, it will not ever return cleanly and when it stops looping it exits the whole program.

To be more specific:
Ask yourself "How do I get the statement `state=9` executed?" That is your goal.
Not hoping for random characters is the key to achieve that.
Also to NOT execute the `exit(200)` statement before that goal is achieved.

You need to achieve two things:

1. Get the statement `state=9` executed, because otherwise your ratio will be low.
   The to be tested code has been deviously designed to make this hard of course.
2. Do not have the statement `exit(200);` executed before first goal, otherwise you won't get multiple tests executed.

For 1 you have to use the function `char inputChar()`, because it is the only one which influences the `if`s.
For 2 you have to use the function `inputString`, becaue it will otherwise do execute the undesired early exit.

I recommend to stop reading here and first try your own hand at programming this.

Do debug before you read on.

Think before you read on.

Program before you read on.

Really, do not read on.

I mean it.

```
char inputChar()
{
    int static charstate=0; /* function internal state counter, starts with 0 */

    /* the following lines are intentionally written
       to be similar to the code to be tested */

    char                testchar='['; /* get tested code from state 0 to 1 */
    if (charstate == 1) testchar='('; /* get tested code from state 1 to 2 */
    if (charstate == 2) testchar='{'; /* get tested code from state 2 to 3 */
    if (charstate == 3) testchar=' '; /* get tested code from state 3 to 4 */
    if (charstate == 4) testchar='a'; /* get tested code from state 4 to 5 */
    if (charstate == 5) testchar='x'; /* get tested code from state 5 to 6 */
    if (charstate == 6) testchar='}'; /* get tested code from state 6 to 7 */
    if (charstate == 7) testchar=']'; /* get tested code from state 7 to 8 */
    if (charstate == 8) testchar=')'; /* get tested code from state 8 to 9 */

    /* synchronise function internal state counter */
    charstate ++; /* only once, do not do this inside the ifs,
                     that would cause a fall through... */

    /* return the character which will achieve the next state in each loop iteration */
    return testchar;
}

char *inputString()
{

    int static stringstate=0; /* function internal state counter, starts with 0 */

    static char s[6];
    s[0] = '#'; /* intentionally avoid triggering the last test case */
    s[1] = 'e';
    s[2] = 's';
    s[3] = 'e';
    s[4] = 't';
    s[5] = '\0';

    /* I left your code as much as possible similar to what you had,
       there are other ways. */


    if (stringstate!=9) /* wait for it ... */
    { /* not yet */}
    else
    {
        /* in state 9, all the previous if statements have been tested */
        s[0]='r'; /* trigger the last, terminal, test branch */
    }


    /* synchronise function internal state counter */
    stringstate++; 

    return s;
}
```

Actually I believe that achieving 80% can be done by not ever returning the magic string, then the random characters might get you there in the end. But why stop at 80%?
And seeing that the teacher outputs the iterations, it will probably not get you best marks if the millions of loops that takes is seen.
For extra bonus points (or at least a snack), I recommend using the fact that they output the string, too. Have the test output a witty message to the teacher:
"Hi"
"Sir." or "Mam."
"Nice"
"goal."
"Can"
"I"
"have"
"cake?"
"reset"

Should they then bring cake they have my respect. ;-)
Not so much if they fail to find this, my answer. This is why I recommded not to read on. If you do this yourself your final exam grades will be better on the long run.
Really, really resist to use my solution.